# categories are not shown in menu

Tags: magento2, category, menu

I am in Magento 2.3.4,
I have added a main category to the root, but the menu does not show me in the front-end of the e-commerce
[image: In the image it is shown that the category is enabled to be shown in the munu, however, it does not appear, is there a way to do it?]

In the image it is shown that the category is enabled to be shown in the munu, however, it does not appear, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The category tree that is displayed in the menu needs to have its root assigned to the current store.

From the backend, that is in `Stores/All Stores`

[image]

If the root category is new, it may be useful to run the indexes: `php bin/magento index:reindex`

Comment: I have all those options except the Root Category ;(

Comment: added a suggestion in my answer now

Comment: I think he found what is happening, he is taking a default menu and not the one I have created